# PHP file is not doing anything with String URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

I'm still very new to ajax and jquery, so sorry for the title, I didn't know how to phrase my question.

I'm having a problem with my URL string send: I have a `Form` set up which allows users to enter currency details as seen below, once the submit button has be pressed i want the data to be sent to a PHP file while having the page not redirect and putting what was sent in the text area below as XML.

I have the JQuery sending the string(to much data i dont want the operation or the textarea to be sent), but the PHP file is not doing anything with the data

Here's my code and my screenshots:
The `Form`:

```
  <form name="myform"   id="myform" method="get">

 <input type="radio" name="operation" value="1" id="Post" 
onclick="displayFunctionPost()"> Post
 <input type="radio" name="operation" value="2" id="Put" 
onclick="displayFunctionPut()"> Put
 <input type="radio" name="operation" value="3" id="Delete" 
 onclick="displayFunctionDelete()"> Delete
 <br>
 Currency Code:
   <br>

    <input type="text" name="currencycode" id="currencycode" 
placeholder="Code" disabled>
    <!--currency form-->
    <br>
    Currency Name
    <br>
    <input type="text" name= "currencyname" id="currencyname" 
  placeholder="name" disabled>
   <br>
   <!---rates form--->  
    Rate(£=1):
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="rate" id="rate" placeholder="rate" disabled>
  <!---countries form-->
    <br>
   Countries (comma separated if 1+)
   <br>
    <input type="text" name= "countries" id="countries" placeholder="countries" disabled>
<br>

 <!---xml response--->
   <br>
   Response Message:
   <br>
   <div id="textarea"><textarea id="textarea" cols="70" rows="5"></textarea> 
</div>

   <input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" >

</form>
```

And here is the JQuery I have so far:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#Submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
         var data = "&currencyname="+currencyname+"&currencycode="+currencycode+"&rate="+rate+"&countries=";
   var data = $('#myform').serialize();


   $.ajax({
    type:    'get',
    cache:    false,
    url:      'currPut.php',
    data:     data,
    processData: false, 
    contentType: false,
    success:  function( data ) {
      alert('test ');      
    }

  });

        }); 
        });
    </script>
```

And here's the PHP file:

```
 <?php


@date_default_timezone_set("GMT"); 
$xml=new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$xml->formatOutput=true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
$xml->load('rates.xml');

if(!$xml)
 {
   $currencies=$xml->createElement("currencies");
  $xml->appendChild($currencies);
}
 else
 {
  $currencies=$xml->firstChild;
}

 if (isset($_GET['Submit']))
  {
    $curcode = $_GET['currency-code'];
    $newrate = $_GET['rate'];
    $cname = $_GET['currency-name'];
    $countries = $_GET['countries'];
    $today = date("F j,g:i a");   

    $curr=$xml->createElement("currency");
    $currencies->appendChild($curr);


    $currate=$xml->createElement("code",$curcode);
    $curr->appendChild($currate);
    $currate->setAttribute("rate",$newrate);


    $name=$xml->createElement("cname",$cname);
    $curr->appendChild($name);

    $places=$xml->createElement("cntry",$countries);
    $curr->appendChild($places);


    $xml->save('rates.xml');




 }
 ?>
```

[This is the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsD6j.jpg).

[And this is the console](https://imgur.com/a/081FgqX).

Comment: This is either a client-side problem, or a server-side problem. Figure out which it is, and then remove the irrelevant tags and code from your question. Use your browser's inspector. Does the request get sent as expected? Is the response as expected?

Comment: You have `name="currencycode"` but `$_GET['currency-code']`. They don't match because of the hyphen difference.

Comment: And the same thing for `currencyname`.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses i will try these out!